# Integer expression expected BASH scripting IF statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am trying to insert names and numbers in a text file. I have wrote a short script for the learning purpose.

```
v= expr $# % 2
echo $v
if [ "$v" -eq 0 ]; then
    i=1
    while [ "$i" -lt $# ]
    do
        echo "$i    $i+1" >> database
        i=$((i+1))
    done
echo "User(s) successfully added \n\v"
else
    echo "Arguments are not complete";
fi
```

When i enter two arguments, the shell output is as follows

```
0                     # (The value of variable v)
./myscript: line 3: [: : integer expression expected
Arguments are not complete  # (else statement is executed)
```

When i replace -eq to == in line 3 (if statement), error msg is gone but still the IF statement doesn't execute as i expect.

```
0              # (output of variable v)
Arguments are not complete # (else statement is executed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the variable assignment in `$(...)` ("command substitution"):

```
v=$(expr $# % 2)
```

In the `if` statement, `-eq` should be correct. Also, to make sure it works, I would use double square brackets (this might depend on the shell you use):

`if [[ ${v} -eq 0 ]]; then`

Comment: Thank you, I have added double brackets in the IF statement and it worked. Kindly explain whats the difference in the single and double brackets in if statement.
I also want to read the arguments passed to the script. I want to read it in such manner e.g for i = 1, $($i) should read $1 (argument first).

Comment: The difference between single and double brackets is nicely explained here: (http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash) Your idea for the `for` loop is almost complete, you just need a sequence to iterate over, you can also do this with command substitution: `for i in $(seq 1 $#); do <code> ; done`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is the failure to use command substitution to capture the result of the `expr` command: `v=$( expr $# % 2 )`. However, 
`expr` is no longer needed for arithmetic; use an arithmetic expression just as you did to increment `i`.

```
v=$(( $# % 2 ))
```